# Error to put in bold text - Objective-C

Tags: iphone, objective-c, bold

I'm trying to put "bold" on a part of a text, but I can't do it.

I'm using this:

```
  NSMutableAttributedString *string = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"this is a part of the text"];
  NSRange selectedRange = NSMakeRange(5, 10); 

  [string beginEditing];

  [string addAttribute:NSFontAttributeName
          value:[NSFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size:12.0]
          range:selectedRange];
  [string endEditing];
```

I get an error "use of undeclared identifier NSFontAttributeName";

How can I do it?

Comment: It seems you're missing an extension: google for "NSAttributedString Application Kit".

Answer (score 3):

As of iOS 6.0, `NSFontAttributeName` should work fine. For docs check NSAttributedString UIKit Additions. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/NSAttributedString_UIKit_Additions/

Answer (score 2):

`NSFontAttributeName` is a constant defined in AppKit on the Mac, it doesn't exist on iOS. In fact, UIKit doesn't provide additions for styling and drawing `NSAttributedString` instances. There's a blog post I found that shows [how to use the underlying Core Text attributes](http://iphonedevelopment.blogspot.com/2011/03/attributed-strings-in-ios.html).

Comment: This is no longer true as of iOS 6